# iOS - Receiving FCM push messages in foreground

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift4

Using Swift 4 and Xcode 10,
I would like to know if it's possible to use Firebase push notification service (cloud messaging) for just receiving push notifications in foreground mode only (no need for background). I would like to update the user with new data when he's in foreground mode without the need for the user to do a refresh.

The thing is that i don't want to ask for notifications permission from the user as he should not be aware of the "real-time updates" i'm doing for him.

I've managed to achieve this by using FCM feature called "Direct FCM channel messages", but the issue for me is that it has some kind of queuing mechanism and when the user is in background mode and then comes back to the app (foreground mode) he gets all the updates he was missing. I don't want this "queuing mechanism" to happen.

I would appreciate any kind of help!
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Hey Eitan Aflalo this is same issue one my friend face.

1> You have to set project setup Capabilities on Push Notification.
2> Use notification identifier. Follow below step.

i hope this work.

```
extension AppDelegate {  

//MARK:- USER NOTIFICATION DELEGATE

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    print(notification.request.content.userInfo)

    if notification.request.identifier == "rig"{
        completionHandler( [.alert,.sound,.badge])
    }else{
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

}



func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    //Handle the notification
    completionHandler(
        [UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert,
         UNNotificationPresentationOptions.sound,
         UNNotificationPresentationOptions.badge])
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    print(deviceTokenString)

}


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

    print(userInfo)

    switch application.applicationState {
    case .active:
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        if let title = userInfo["title"]
        {
            content.title = title as! String
        }
        if let title = userInfo["text"]
        {
            content.body = title as! String
        }
        content.userInfo = userInfo
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:"rig", content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
            if let getError = error {
                print(getError.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    case .inactive:
        break
    case .background:
        break
    }



}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("i am not available in simulator \(error)")
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
    print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I didn't manage to succeed with your solution. Maybe I'm missing some implementations.. Do you have the full code?

Comment: @Eitan Aflalo Thanks but this the way handling FCM notification, you have use `inactive` and `background` `applicationState`. I hope this is need helpfull. – Pradip Patel 47 mins ago